# Pseudorandom Function Proof

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

Given a set of pseudorandom functions $F=\{f_s^i\}_i$ for each $s\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n$ generated at random; moreover each $f_s^i$ uses a specific PRG $G^i:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^{2n}$, where:

- $G^i(s)=x_1\dots x_nx_{n+1}\dots x_{2n}$ and $G_0^i(s)=x_1\dots x_n$ and $G_1^i(s)=x_{n+1}\dots x_{2n}$
- $f_s^i(1)=G_1^i(s)$
- $f_s^i(0)=G_0^i(s)$

Given $f_s$ from $F$, let us define some new $f_s'$ and $f_s''$ respectively for a PRF $F'=\{{f_s^i}'\}_i$ and $F''=\{{f_s^i}''\}_i$ as follows:

- ${f_s^i}'(x)=f_s^i(0x)f_s^i(1x)$
- ${f_s^i}''(x)=f_s^i(0x)f_s^i(x1)$

I want to check if ${f_s^i}'$ and ${f_s^i}''$ are pseudorandom. So, since  a PRF is defined as $f_s^i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=G_{x_0}^i(\dots G_{x_n}^i(s)\dots)$, then in the first case I would have that:

$${f_s^i}'(x)=f_s^i(0x)f_s^i(1x)=G_0(G_x(s))G_1(G_x(s))=G(G_x(s))$$

so, given $s$ random $G_x(s)$ is random, then ${f_s^i}'$ is a pseudorandom function. So, is the first proof correct? Could I apply the same reasoning even in the second case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if I query x=011...1 to your second candidate?

Comment: It should happen that ${f_s^i}''(1)=f_s^i(01)f_s^i(11)=G(G_1(s)G_1(s))$, and hence $G$ does not receive as input a random string, and hence it is not a good random generator.

Comment: Basically, I'm wondering if my proofs are correct.